# What commits are missing from Master?

Tags: git

I can check what branches a specific commit has gone into by doing:

```
git branch --contains 469bcec
```

Is there anyway I can get what commits have not gone into a specific branch?

For example, is there anyway I can check what commits have not going into Master?

Thanks

Comment: To get all branches where a commit is not present:
`diff <(git branch) <(git branch --contains eb87aa6c)`. Not exactly what you're looking for, but may be part of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is at least close to what you want - not sure if it's an exact match:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all --not master
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify "all commits in a repo regardless of label" (well, internally, there sort-of-is, that's how `git fsck` finds "dangling commit"s) but you would not want that anyway as it would find "temporary, non-branch" commits such as those in `refs/stash` and its reflog.

It's also not clear whether you want to include or exclude commits named via `refs/remotes/`, for instance ("remote branches"), or those named via tags.  However, in general, the way to do this is to start with [talles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20055666/1256452), which uses the `..` syntax: `EXC..INC` means the same thing as `INC --not EXC`, i.e., all commits reachable starting from the "include" point *`INC`*, minus all commits starting from the "exclude" point *`EXC`*.  If the include point is branch `devel` and the exclude point is `master`, this is a list of commits "on `devel`" that are not "on `master`".  (And you can omit either side to mean "use `HEAD`", so `..master` means "include `HEAD`, exclude `master`" which means "all commits on this branch that are not on `master`.)

Using the expanded form, it's possible to ask for all commits reachable from multiple starting "include" points, minus those reachable from an "exclude" point.  So:

```
git log featureA featureB --not master
```

gets you everything on the two feature branches that is not in `master`.

If you want "local branches", though, there is direct way: `git rev-list` has a `--branches` argument.  Using `--branches` means "all local branches".  You can add `=pattern` to pick only branches matching some shell-style pattern, e.g., `--branches='feature*'` to pick up branches `featureA`, `featureB`, and so on, but not branch `devel`.

Feed these to any command that uses `git rev-list`, including `git log`:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --branches --not master
```

There are similar `git rev-list` arguments for tags and remotes, along with `--glob`, which allows you access to the complete reference name space.  Providing `--all` (as in [twalberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056433/1256452)) means the same as `--glob=*`, i.e., include every reference in the `refs` name space—which includes `refs/stash`, not always what you want.

(Also, one last syntactic trick: you can spell `--not master` with `^master`.  This is subtly different from using `--not`: `--not` flips a boolean flag that applies to all subsequent names, while a leading `^` applies only to its one item; so `--not rel1 rel2` "means" the same thing as `^rel1 ^rel2`.  Note that `^commit` is very different from `commit^`.  Ah, git. :-) )

Comment: What a *dense* answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it for all your branches in one command (without scripting), but for specific ones you can do it:

```
git log master..mybranch
```

This lists all revisions present on `mybranch` that aren't on `master`.

You can also use multiple branches on the same command:

```
git log master..mybranch1 master..mybranch2
```

---

For the sake of simplicity you can also add the `--oneline`option and omit the current branch you are on (let's suppose you are on the master branch):

```
git log ..mybranch1 ..mybranch2 --oneline
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: Git 1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014) will include a new `--exclude` option with [commit 10167eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75):

> People often wished a way to tell "`git log --branches`" (and "`git log --remotes --not --branches`") to exclude some local branches from the expansion of "`--branches`" (similarly for "`--tags`", "`--all`" and "`--glob=<pattern>`").
>   Now they have one.

The [git rev-parse](https://github.com/git/git/blob/10167eb251e177349eebf24650d3c0cc26bd0d75/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L180-L186) and [git rev-list](https://github.com/git/git/blob/574d370b0633a89f7d62ec4eac08228b26eea06f/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L177-L190) now mention:

```
--exclude=<glob-pattern>::
```

> Do not include refs matching '`<glob-pattern>`' that the next `--all`, `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or `--glob` would otherwise consider.
>   Repetitions of this option accumulate exclusion patterns up to the next `--all`, `--branches`, `--tags`, `--remotes`, or `--glob` option (other options or arguments do not clear accumlated patterns).
>
> The patterns given should not begin with `refs/heads`, `refs/tags`, or `refs/remotes` when applied to `--branches`, `--tags`, or `--remotes`, respectively, and they must begin with `refs/` when applied to `--glob` or `--all`.
>   If a trailing '`/{asterisk}`' is intended, it must be given explicitly.